# Visual Studio 2008 always build to C:\Users\bin\Debug\MyLibrary.dll

Tags: visual-studio, build, path

Although I have set the output build path to: `..\..\..\..\..\..\bin\Debug\`

All other projects accept the relative path above. Why not that newly added project?

When I choose the FolderDialog to set the output path, press ok then I see the absolute path in the output path textbox. Now I copy paste my relative path into the output path textbox and rebuild. It still puts all stuff in the folder I have previously overwritten via copy/paste ???

Comment: Are you sure that the relative path resolves to where it should?

Answer (score 0):

rebuild this project,and you'd better set the relative path at first

Answer (score 0):

Before I did copy/paste of the relative path. Seems VS08 does not like that. Now I entered all manually and it works???